# Find if any item in the array matches the condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, map-function

I am new to Javascript. Now, Here I have an array which has multiple objects. So, I want to iterate it and if any of the object matches the condition then I want to return a value and stop that loop.

My array of obj is like,

```
var obj =  [ { type: "", numberOfQuestions:"",  technology:"" }, { type: "1", numberOfQuestions:"4",  technology:"abcd" }, { type: "", numberOfQuestions:"6",  technology:"ass" } ]
```

And my condition is,

```
     validateData(data) {
            data.High.map((object) => {
              if((object.type === "") || (object.numberOfQuestions === "") || (object.technology === "")) {
                    return true;
              } else {
                  return false;
              } 
            });
        }
```

So, what I want is that any of the object which has some keys, has empty value for any key, i.e `""` Then I want to return a true value so that I can do some other stuff. 
How can I do this ?

Can anyone please help me.

Comment: You can use Array's **some** method here. some() returns true (whereas find() returns the found value) when the condition matches.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `Array.prototype.some`

```
var array = [...];

function validateData (array) {
  return array.some(item => item.type === '' || item.numberOfQuestions === '' || item.technology === '');
}

validateData(array);
```

It was ES6 solution (with arrow functions).

ES5 solution:

```
function validateData (array) {
  return array.some(function(item) { 
    return item.type === '' || item.numberOfQuestions === '' || item.technology === '';
  });
}
```

Comment: So map is not necessary here ?

Comment: Map is different. Map will create new array with new values (same length as initial array). You don't need this (since your explanation). Some will return boolean. Thats what you need.

Comment: So its returning that the condition has matched then will return true

Comment: Yes. If any of items in array match the condition, then `some` will return true. Otherwise, false.

Comment: Thanks a lot :-)  for your solution. I have one thought in my mind that is is possible like to get which condition went wrong I mean that particular object , like numberOfquestions failed.

Answer (score 3):

You can use filter function for this, which return the array on the condition

```
 var container =  [ { type: "", numberOfQuestions:"",  technology:"" }, { type: "1", numberOfQuestions:"4",  technology:"abcd" }, { type: "", numberOfQuestions:"6",  technology:"ass" } ]

    container.filter((a)=>{ return a['type'] == "" ? a : a['numberOfQuestions'] == "" ? a : a['technology'] == "" ? a : '' }).length > 0 ? true : false;
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, dont use `=` in the object please use `:` . If you want to check the keys dynamically use this code

```
    const validateData = (data) => {
          data.map((object) => {
        Object.keys(object).map((innerObj) => {
        if(object[innerObj] === "") {
                  return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            } 

        })

          });
        } 

        var obj =  [{ type: "", numberOfQuestions:"",  technology:"" }, 
{ type: "1", numberOfQuestions:"4",  technology:"abcd" }, 
{ type: "", numberOfQuestions:"6",  technology:"ass" }];

        validateData(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method

```
var obj =  [ { type: "", numberOfQuestions:"",  technology:"" }, { type: "1", numberOfQuestions:"4",  technology:"abcd" }, { type: "", numberOfQuestions:"6",  technology:"ass" } ]
obj.filter((a)=>{ return a['type'] == "" ? a : a['numberOfQuestions'] == "" ? a : a['technology'] == "" ? a : '' }).length > 0 ? true : false;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work regardless of key names (using es6 syntax).

```
var data =  [ { type: "", numberOfQuestions:"",  technology:"" }, { type: "1", numberOfQuestions:"4",  technology:"abcd" }, { type: "", numberOfQuestions:"6",  technology:"ass" } ]

const checkNull = (data) => data.some(item => Object.keys(item).some(key => item[key] == ''));

console.log(checkNull(data));
```

Answer (score -1):

use array `reduce`

```js
    obj =  [ { type: "", numberOfQuestions:"",  technology:"" }, { type: "1", numberOfQuestions:"4",  technology:"abcd" }, { type: "", numberOfQuestions:"6",  technology:"ass" } ];
    
    obj = obj.find(function(item){ if (!(item.type === '' || item.numberOfQuestions === '' || item.technology === '')){ return item; } });
    
    console.log('array : ', obj);
```