# Check if variable is less then every value in array

Tags: javascript

I have a variable with number and array. For example:

```
var arr = [10, 13, 17];
var number = 8;
```

I want to check if **number** is less then every value in **arr** and if true do something like this:

```
var arr = [10, 13, 17];
var number = 8;
if (number < arr[]) {
// do something
} else {
// do something
}
```

Could you please help me to solve this issue?

Comment: `arr.some(e => number < e)`

Comment: @ASDFGerte - *"I want to check if number is less then any all values in arr..."* I think you meant `every`, not `some`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I read the title, and went by that.

Comment: The question is ungrammatical and ambiguous: "any all values" should be either "any values" or "all values", so the question needs to be edited to clarify this.

Comment: @ASDFGerte - Quite. :-)

Comment: There has to be a dupetarget for this, but I'm not finding it... Tricky to search for.

Comment: Here's one from 2018 but I bet it was a duplicate, too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52625038/find-if-any-item-in-the-array-matches-the-condition And of course, it depends on the whole any/all thing. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var arr = [10, 13, 17];
var number = 8,
  number1 = 12;

if (number < Math.min(...arr)) {
  console.log("do something");
} else {
  console.log("do something else");
}

if (number1 < Math.min(...arr)) {
  console.log("do something");
} else {
  console.log("do something else");
}
```

Answer (score 7):

JavaScript doesn't provide a way to do that for you, you have to do it yourself.

> I want to check if number is less then any all values in arr...

It would be either "any value in `arr`" or "all values in `arr`". "any all values in `arr`" doesn't make sense.

If you mean "`number` is less than **all** values in `arr`", probably the easiest way is the [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) function on arrays:

```
if (arr.every(e => number < e)) {
```

If you mean "`number` is less than **any** value in `arr`", you want [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) instead:

```
if (arr.some(e => number < e)) {
```

One good thing about that is they short-circuit: As soon as `every`/`some` knows the result, it stops looping. For `every`, that means the first time the callback returns a falsy value; for `some`, that means the first time the callback returns a truthy value.

Comment: Good answer, and the point about short-circuiting is important.

Answer (score 1):

How about the use of min() function?

```
Math.min(...arr);
```

should return the minimum value of the array.
Its an ES6 function.

Comment: *"Its an ES6 function."* No, it isn't. `Math.min` has been in JavaScript since the beginning (it's in the ECMAScript 1st edition standard, and I'm pretty sure it predates *that*). Array spread notation is ES2015 ("ES6"), perhaps that's what you meant. In ES5 it would be `Math.min.apply(Math, arr)` (though `Math.min.apply(null, arr)` works).

Comment: Not to nitpick, but `...` isn't (and can't be) an operator. Operators can't do what  spread and rest do. :-)

Comment: Okay, you're right it does a lot a lot more than an operator... :-) 
But I know several coding instances that call it a "Spread operator" ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Simple approach is to check for the minimum of an array and then compare your variable against that. If your variable is the lowest number then it will be equal to the minimum of an array.

```
var arr = [10, 13, 17];
var number = 8;

if(number > Math.min.apply(null, arr)) {
 console.log("at least one value is lower than your number");
} else {
 console.log("no value is lower than your number");
}
```

Comment: This solution should work, but won't short-circuit. For example if `arr` has a million elements, but the first one is out of range, you shouldn't need to look at the rest of them.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two examples on how to achieve that:

```js
var arr = [10, 13, 17];
var number = 8;

// Old school version
const isSmallest = (n, list) => {
  let hasSmaller = false

  for (let i = 0; hasSmaller === false && i < list.length; i++) {
    hasSmaller = n > list[i];
  }

  return !hasSmaller;
}

// Array.prototype.every version
const isSmallest2 = (n, list) => {
  return list.every(item => n < item)
}

console.log(isSmallest(number, arr));
console.log(isSmallest2(number, arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can use for..in, for of, map and filter. 
Lets see 2 examples.

E.g `for of`

```js
var arr = [10, 13, 17];
var number = 8;

for(const element of arr) {
    if( number < element){
        // do something
        console.log(`${number} > ${element}`)
    }
    else {
        //do something
        console.log(`${number} <= ${element}`)
    }
}
```

E.g `E.g map`

```js
var arr = [10, 13, 17];
var number = 8;

arr.map((element) => number < element ? console.log(`${number} > ${element}`) : console.log(`${number} <= ${element}`))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for performance;

```
function isMin(num){
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i]<num){
      return false
    }
  }

  return true
}
```